# ¿Dónde poner los break en un loop while True?

Tags: python

Busqué por ahí un loop que detecta cuando el usuario presione una tecla, pero realmente esto me confunde mucho. En el código se nota un poco la estructura de cómo va la cosa, pero no sé cómo 'terminar el loop' y dónde colocar el `break`. Es simplemente un juego, con un árbol de decisiones.

(Supuestamente, también hay que agregar un `except: break`)

El sistema va así: pasa un 'suceso', y en ese suceso hay un determinado número de 'decisiones'. Decidí que era más bonito detectar la tecla pulsada que un simple input, así que se crea un loop hasta que detecte la tecla pulsada. Sin embargo, hay más `if` por ahí, y realmente el juego no acaba hasta que haya un 'suceso' en específico. No sé si me explico bien.

NOTA: Estoy usando varias librerias (como la es Rich), y hay algunas funciones detrás del código.

```py
# Juego
def main():
        
    # Factor de suerte
    suerte = randint(1,20)

    limpiar()
    centrar()

    # ¿Empezar una nueva partida?
    # 1. Sí | 2. No
    panelSuceso("¿Empezar una nueva partida?")
    panelDecisiones("[bold yellow]1.[/] [bright_white]Sí[/] [rosy_brown]|[/] [bold yellow]2.[/] [bright_white]No[/]")

    while True:
        try:
            # ¿Empezar una nueva partida?
            # 1. Sí
            if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
                # Despiertas...
                # 1. Acercarse | 2. Evitar la caravana
                decision("Despiertas y recuerdas que debes seguir tu camino. Te encuentras con una caravana en el camino.", "[bold yellow]1.[/] [bright_white]Sí[/] [rosy_brown]|[/] [bold yellow]2.[/] [bright_white]No[/]")
                while True:
                    try:
                        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
                            # Despiertas...
                            # 1. Acercarse
                            decision("Decides acercarte a la caravana. Eran bandidos.", "[bold yellow]1.[/] [bright_white]Enfrentarte a ellos[/] [rosy_brown]|[/] [bold yellow]2.[/] [bright_white]Escapar[/]")
                            while True:
                                try:
                                    if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
                                        # Decides acercarte...
                                        # 1. Enfrentarte a ellos 
                                        if suerte > 10:
                                            panelSuceso("les ganas")
                                        if suerte <= 10:
                                            panelSuceso("pierdes")
                                            time.sleep(1.5)
                                            exit()
                                    if keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
                                        # Decides acercarte...
                                        # 2. Escapar
                                        if suerte > 10:
                                            panelSuceso("logras escapar")
                                        if suerte <= 10:
                                            panelSuceso("pierdes")
                                            time.sleep(1.5)
                                            exit()
                        if keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
                            # Despiertas...
                            # 2. Evitar la caravana
                            decision("Prefieres seguir con tu camino y evitar la caravana. Después de un tiempo, ves a lo lejos un pueblito.", "[bold yellow]1.[/] [bright_white]Ir al pueblo[/] [rosy_brown]|[/] [bold yellow]2.[/] [bright_white]Ignorarlo[/]")
                            while True:
                                try:
                                    if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
                                        # Prefieres seguir con tu camino...
                                        # 1. Ir al pueblo
                                        if suerte > 10:
                                            panelSuceso("llegas al pueblo")
                                        if suerte <= 10:
                                            panelSuceso("pierdes")
                                            time.sleep(1.5)
                                            exit()
                                    if keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
                                        # Prefieres seguir con tu camino...
                                        if suerte > 10:
                                            panelSuceso("lo ignoras y te vas")
                                        if suerte <= 10:
                                            panelSuceso("pierdes")
                                            time.sleep(1.5)
                                            exit()
            # ¿Empezar una nueva partida?
            # 2. No
            if keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
                limpiar()
                centrar()
                panelSuceso("Cerrando el juego...")
                time.sleep(1.5)
                limpiar()
                exit()

main()
```

Comment: No se me ocurre como ayudarte, pero te quería avisar que la librería keyboard va a detectar las pulsaciones de tecla incluso si la consola está minimizada.

Answer (score 0):

El ciclo **while** se utiliza cuando se desea iterar sobre algo varias veces, hasta que la sentencia se vuelva False. En tu caso, al colocar **While True** terminas con un bucle infinito ya que esa sentencia jamás será **False**. Esto suele ser algo malo. Los bucles infinitos deben evitarse y se conocen como errores lógicos.

El ciclo **while** también puede interrumpirse mediante el uso de la [ruptura incorporada](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter5_loops.html#the-while-loop), en tu caso que colocaste **While True** puedes meter en un **If** el **break** para que el bucle sea interrumpido al entrar a la condicional.

También te recomiendo que le des una revisada a la documentación de Python sobre todo a las [Condicionales If/Else](https://python-essentials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/if-else.html#if-else) y al [Manejo de excepciones](https://www.python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter7_exception_handling.html#chapter-7-exception-handling).

Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que te comento en tu código:

```
# Juego
def main():

# Se inicializan las variables que usaremos como contadores
i = int(0)
j = int(0)

# Factor de suerte
suerte = randint(1,20)

limpiar()
centrar()

# ¿Empezar una nueva partida?
# 1. Sí | 2. No
panelSuceso("¿Empezar una nueva partida?")
panelDecisiones("[bold yellow]1.[/] [bright_white]Sí[/] [rosy_brown]|[/] [bold yellow]2.[/] [bright_white]No[/]")

# El loop se va a repetir hasta que la sentencia sea False:
# El contador i vale 0 y 0 es menor que 3, entonces esta sentencia es True.
# Cuando el contador sea igual o mayor que 3, entonces la sentencia será False y el ciclo se detendrá.
while i < 3:
    # Colocamos nuestro try/except
    try:
        # ¿Empezar una nueva partida?
        # 1. Sí
        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
            # Despiertas...
            # 1. Acercarse | 2. Evitar la caravana
            decision("Despiertas y recuerdas que debes seguir tu camino. Te encuentras con una caravana en el camino.", "[bold yellow]1.[/] [bright_white]Sí[/] [rosy_brown]|[/] [bold yellow]2.[/] [bright_white]No[/]")
            # El loop se repite 3 veces
            while j < 3:
                if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
                    # Despiertas...
                    # 1. Acercarse
                    decision("Decides acercarte a la caravana. Eran bandidos.", "[bold yellow]1.[/] [bright_white]Enfrentarte a ellos[/] [rosy_brown]|[/] [bold yellow]2.[/] [bright_white]Escapar[/]")
                    # El loop se repite 3 veces
                    while True:
                        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
                            # Decides acercarte...
                            # 1. Enfrentarte a ellos 
                            if suerte > 10:
                                panelSuceso("les ganas")
                                break
                            else if suerte <= 10:
                                panelSuceso("pierdes")
                                time.sleep(1.5)
                                exit()
                        else if keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
                            # Decides acercarte...
                            # 2. Escapar
                            if suerte > 10:
                                panelSuceso("logras escapar")
                                break
                            else if suerte <= 10:
                                panelSuceso("pierdes")
                                time.sleep(1.5)
                                exit()
                        # El numero que se ingreso es diferente al 1 y 2
                        else
                            panelSuceso("La opcion ingresada es incorrecta!")
                else if keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
                    # Despiertas...
                    # 2. Evitar la caravana
                    decision("Prefieres seguir con tu camino y evitar la caravana. Después de un tiempo, ves a lo lejos un pueblito.", "[bold yellow]1.[/] [bright_white]Ir al pueblo[/] [rosy_brown]|[/] [bold yellow]2.[/] [bright_white]Ignorarlo[/]")
                    while True:
                        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
                            # Prefieres seguir con tu camino...
                            # 1. Ir al pueblo
                            if suerte > 10:
                                panelSuceso("llegas al pueblo")
                                break
                            if suerte <= 10:
                                panelSuceso("pierdes")
                                time.sleep(1.5)
                                exit()
                        else if keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
                            # Prefieres seguir con tu camino...
                            if suerte > 10:
                                panelSuceso("lo ignoras y te vas")
                                break
                            if suerte <= 10:
                                panelSuceso("pierdes")
                                time.sleep(1.5)
                                exit()
                        # El numero que se ingreso es diferente al 1 y 2
                        else
                            panelSuceso("La opcion ingresada es incorrecta!")
                # El numero que se ingreso es diferente al 1 y 2
                else
                    panelSuceso("La opcion ingresada es incorrecta!")
                # Le sumamos 1 a nuestro contador
                j++
        # ¿Empezar una nueva partida?
        # 2. No
        else if keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
            limpiar()
            centrar()
            panelSuceso("Cerrando el juego...")
            time.sleep(1.5)
            limpiar()
            exit()
        # El numero que se ingreso es diferente al 1 y 2
        # ¿?
        else
            panelSuceso("La opcion ingresada es incorrecta!")
    # Si algo sale mal, aqui cachamos la excepcion
    except
        panelSuceso("Ha ocurrido una excepcion!")
    # Le sumamos 1 a nuestro contador
    i++
main()
```